# How can I find the most common number in an input?

Tags: c++

This is a very abstracted explanation of what I'm doing:

Say I have a text file full of numbers separated by newlines. Right now, I take these numbers and put them in a `map<int, int>`, where the key is the number, and the value is the frequency.

My end goal is a list of numbers sorted by frequency. How can I go about doing this? Note that a frequency can obviously show up more than once. The way I was thinking was to make a `struct` containing both a number and its frequency, and define `<` so that it never returns equality. I would then iterate through the map, putting all the elements into that struct and then into a set.

Comment: I'm confused about what the numbers in your file are. Are they numbers, and you're trying to count how many times those numbers show up in order to calculate the frequency?

Also, are you looking for just the most common number? Because you can most likely do that a lot more efficiently than making a sorted list of frequencies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you've built the frequency map, copy its pairs to a `std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >` then `std::sort` the latter with the 3-args version of `std::sort`, which takes the comparator as the third arg; as a comparator, you can use one that compares the `.second` fields of the pairs first, and the `.first` ones (if you want) only to disambiguate the ordering of pairs whose `.second` fields are equal (but I don't think you really need the last bit since you don't care about the ordering for cases with equal frequency, do you?).

Comment: Cool, that works great! I came over to C++ from Java a little bit ago... never used a vector before.
And to answer your question, I don't really care but I might as well.

Comment: @deftonix, the only reason my last question needs to be asked is that C++'s `std::sort` (differently from Python's, and I believe Java's), per the C++ standard, is _not_ a "stable" sort, i.e., does not guarantee the order of items deemed by the comparator to be "equal" stays unchanged (since on copying from the map to the vector you _do_ have things in sorted order by key, a hypothetical stable sort would only need comparison on the `.second` fields to give the same results as secondarily-comparing on `.first` gives in reality;-).

Answer (score 1):

If this is simply an operation you wish to do on it's own (rather than a component you want to use), the most practical way for me would be to do something like this:

```
sort <filename> | uniq -c | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sort -rn
```

Of course it doesn't scale well compared to a linear algorithm, but it performs reasonably well for every day tasks, and it has the added advantage that you don't need to reinvent the wheel yourself.

---

**EDIT**: sort" sorts your file ; "uniq" groups all consecutive lines that are the same into a pair [frequency] [item] pair, for instance

```
12
12
24
25
25
25
```

becomes

```
    2 12
    1 24
    3 25
```

then I remove the trailing space with "sed" (if this doesn't work, it is because there is sometimes an issue with the way the tab character is inputted), then I sort the output according to frequency (the "n" option asks for a numerical sort, instead of lexicographic; the "r" option asks for a reverse sorting).

If you want to select another field for the sorting (say, because the number you are actually interested in counting the frequency are the THIRD field of a tab delimited line), then you can use "sort"'s selection feature:

```
sort -t'\t' -k3 <filename> | ...
```

This says that your input is a tab-delimited list of fields, and that you want to sort according to the third field.

---

**EDIT 2**: here is the line to do this according to the fourth field (and to remove all other fields)

```
cut -d'\t' -f4 <filename> | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sort -rn
```

Comment: Mind explaining to me how this works? My shell skills are only ok. And what if there were a bunch of extraneous characters on each line? Could I modify that command to strip all but the 4th tab-deliminated item?

Comment: If you want to *strip* (and not just ignore), you would use "cut" to only keep the fourth field. The line would then be: cut -d'\t' -f4 <filename> | sort | ...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `std:pair` of the `std::map` and insert them into a `std::priority_queue`.  Use a comparison function from the value.

Once you have your priority queue you can iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

In year 2022, the approach would be different. We can take advantage of new language features. And new containers.

Here especially the `std::unordered_map` or the `std::mulitiset`.

Then the task will be much simpler and the resulting code will be shorter.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Create aliases. Save typing work and make code more readable
using Pair = std::pair<int, std::size_t>;

// Standard approach for counter
using Counter = std::unordered_map<Pair::first_type, Pair::second_type>;

// Sorted values will be stored in a multiset
struct Comp { bool operator ()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const { return (p1.second == p2.second) ? p1.first<p2.first : p1.second>p2.second; } };
using Sorter = std::multiset<Pair, Comp>;
// ------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {

    // Open the source file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inFileStream{ "r:\\file.txt" }; inFileStream) {

        // Here we will count the extensions of the file names
        Counter counter{};

        // Read all values from file and count them
        for (Pair::first_type i{}; inFileStream >> i; counter[i]++)
            ;

        // Sort them 
        Sorter sorter(counter.begin(), counter.end());

        // Show result to the user. 
        for (const auto& [value, count] : sorter) std::cout << value << " --> " << count << '\n';
    } 
    else {
        // file could not be opened
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Input file could not be opened\n\n";
    }
}
```